# Enabling ProGuard in Android

Tags: android, proguard

I plan on using ProGuard to obfuscate the code of my Android app. I have been researching about it. Most of the articles and videos on YouTube seem to be out dated. From all what I have gathered, here is what need to be done:

1. In the `project.properties` class I will have to uncomment the line:

   `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt`
2. [I am using Crashlytics](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202143-eclipse-with-proguard) and it says that to have informative stack traces, I must add a line to `ProGuard` configuration:

   `-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable`

I am guessing that the above line is appended to `proguard-project.txt`?

And then that's it. Please correct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct. In your `project.properties` you need to define the
   path/filename for your Proguard configuration file, e.g.

   ```
   proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
   ```

   (in this case proguard-project.txt sits in the project's root folder)
2. Also correct. As per the Proguard [documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/usage.html):

   > -keepattributes [attribute_filter]
   >
   > Specifies any optional attributes to be preserved.
   >
   > ...
   >
   > You should also keep the **SourceFile** and **LineNumberTable**
   >   attributes for **producing useful obfuscated stack traces**. Finally, you
   >   may want to keep annotations if your code depends on them. Only
   >   applicable when obfuscating.

Comment: Elaborate point 1. please. Why did you change the value ? :) WHat does it show ?

Comment: Ah figured! it shows the location of the `proguard-project` file :)

Comment: I changed the value so that it points to a file (proguard-project.txt) within my project folder, so the Proguard settings are specific to the project.

Comment: Okay, I have some open-source third party libraries. From what I have read, open-source libraries tend of be less of a problem in `ProGuard`. What has been your experience with it ? :)

Comment: I haven't had any issues so far producing perfectly working apks with Proguard, whether using open source libraries or not, but that's just me. The general advice is however you should thoroughly test your app after building with Proguard.